# Replace MS Cardspace UI

Tags: cardspace

Is it possible to replace Microsoft Cardspace UI with your own? Or use Cardspace without any UI?

Answer (score 0):

Google for Chuck Mortimer who wrote a Cardspace UI for Firefox.